# Trying to write a function that installed a package if not already installed, then load it

Tags: r, package

I am trying to write a function that can check if a package is installed, will install it if it is not, and then include it.

I first tried

```
loadLibraryAndInstallPackageIfNotFound <- function(name) {
  if(!require(name))
    install.packages(name);
  library(name);
}
```

But the package name is not going through correctly using this code.

After some more search I tried:

```
loadLibraryAndInstallPackageIfNotFound <- function(name) {
  if(!require(name,character.only = TRUE))
    install.packages(name,character.only = TRUE);
  library(name,character.only = TRUE);
}

loadLibraryAndInstallPackageIfNotFound(envDocument);
loadLibraryAndInstallPackageIfNotFound(kableExtra);
```

I'm wondering if I'm over-using `character.only = TRUE` in there...

But I'm now getting:

> Error in paste0("package:", package) : object 'envDocument' not found

Is there a solution to make this function work?

Comment: Can you pass that as a string i.e. `loadLibraryAndInstallPackageIfNotFound("kableExtra")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we pass the argument as a string, it would work

```
loadLibraryAndInstallPackageIfNotFound <- function(name) {
  if(!require(name,character.only = TRUE))
    install.packages(name,character.only = TRUE);
  library(name,character.only = TRUE);
}

loadLibraryAndInstallPackageIfNotFound("envDocument");
```

---

Otherwise, convert the unquoted 'name' to a string with `deparse/substitute`

```
loadLibraryAndInstallPackageIfNotFound <- function(name) {
  name <- deparse(substitute(name))
  if(!require(name,character.only = TRUE))
    install.packages(name,character.only = TRUE);
  library(name,character.only = TRUE);
}

loadLibraryAndInstallPackageIfNotFound(envDocument);
```

Comment: Thank you, I can indeed pass names as strings. I was focusing on the function while the mistake was in my function calls. (I can only validate this as answer in ~10 minutes.)